# Notation for indefinite integrals

Tags: notation

The notation $\int f(x)\, dx$ for indefinite integrals is, from a theoretical syntactic perspective, a beast.  As far as I can tell, this notation binds the variable $x$ in $f(x)$, finds the "general antiderivative" of the resulting function --- obtaining strictly speaking not a function, but either a set of functions or a function of both $x$ and some "locally constant" function $C$ on the domain of $f$ --- then "applies" the result to a new free variable $x$ (and perhaps $C$) that is required to be syntactically the same as the original variable $x$ that got bound.  Alternatively, one could regard $x$ (and, I guess, $C$) as being "implicitly bound" in the result.

I am curious: is there any general-purpose proof assistant in which one can define a notation that behaves like this?  (Laying aside the entirely reasonable question of whether one *should* do such a terrible thing...)

Comment: I feel there are two parts to your question.  (1) How to internally represent the antiderivative of f(x) with respect to x?  For example, is it a lambda term?  What is it’s type?  (2) How close can one get to the standard notation?  Are you looking for exactly that notation, or for example can the x be alone instead of in dx?

Comment: Lean had the following notation for [definite integrals](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/blob/master/src/measure_theory/integral/interval_integral.lean#L1734).  `∫ x in u..v, f x`.  This handles the binder over `x`.  I don't know if this is close enough, but also see this version: `∫ x in a..b, f x ∂μ`.  I guess it could be adapted into an indefinate integral once one decides what an indefinite integral of a function is in Lean.  Once that is known, one could probably in theory make `∫ f x ∂x` an abbreviation for `antiderivative (lambda x, f x)`

Comment: Or maybe in Lean the x really does need to go in front since the integral symbol is acting as a binder.   Also I suspect the value of this integral is arbitrarily defined if f is not integrable, which would require classical logic to define.

Comment: Definite integrals are much easier since they don't have the problem of reintroducing a free variable.  I would expect that most any proof assistant supporting user-defined binding notations would be able to reproduce something like `∫ x in u..v, f x`.  Being able to put the `dx` after the `f x` would be cute, but isn't really what I'm asking about; I'm more interested in how to deal with the fact that the indefinite integral is not a number but still an expression involving the same free variable `x` (plus a new locally constant function).

Comment: I don't think the indefinite integral should be thought of as an expression (and it can't be in the presence of functional extensionality, right?  Two different expressions can both be the indefinite integral of f).  It seems that whatever the indefinite integral is, it is a function of the integrand function. One simple approach is to define the indefinite integral as `∫ x, f x` as the family of functions `lambda a x, ∫ t in a..x, (lambda x, f x) t` or as `lambda x c, (∫ t in 0..x, (lambda x, f x) t) + c`.  Or am I thinking of this is the wrong way?

Comment: Well, if two different expressions would define the same function when abstracted, then they are also equal pointwise, no?  I don't mean "expression" in the sense of an element of an *internal* abstract syntax tree, I just used that word to distinguish $x^2$ from $\lambda x. x^2$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You want to have `∫ x, 2 * x` have a free variable `x`. The only possibility I see is to make it something like an abbreviation for `λ c, (∫ t in 0..x, (λ x, 2 * x) t) + c`.  I don't know if this is possible in Lean, which I guess is your question.  (I'm trying to think if I would ever write $d/dx (\int 2x dx)$ in calculus, but I guess it doesn't matter.  Your question now makes sense to me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Lean 4

As Lean 4 is based on a general (but still hygienic) macro system, there are no restrictions on binding structure. So you can in fact use the same variable as both a binder and a reference outside of the binder if you think that is a good idea.

```
variable [Mul R] [Add R] (integral : (R → R) → (R → R))

local notation "∫" f "∂" x => integral (fun x => f) x

def demo (x : R) : R := ∫ x * x + x ∂x
```

Comment: This is nice, because it will just work: `integral (fun x => f)` returns a map on the reals which is then applied to `x`. By the way, do you not need a space between `∂` and `x` in the demo (how does Lean know `∂x` isn't a single name)?

Comment: @AndrejBauer `∂` is not a valid part of an (unescaped) Lean identifier (Unicode seems to agree on that), so `∂x` is parsed as two tokens by the longest match rule

Comment: @AndrejBauer No, Lean does the lexing and parsing stuff different from Agda. The double quote declares a token, which will affect how Lean recogizes names after it.

Comment: That's rather nice. So you could write `∫x*x*+x∂x` without any spaces? (I am not advocating this.)

Comment: Indeed, and it doesn't even look too bad with highlighting in the editor

Comment: Also fun: if you put your cursor on the first `x` (the parameter), the Lean server will highlight the last `x` as a reference. For any of the `x` in the middle, it will highlight all the middle ones as well as the last one (as the binder). And finally, for the last `x`, it will highlight all of them. The notation breaks transitivity of the highlighting relation.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, we can set up the usual integral notation which binds the variable, as it should.

Agda:

```
module integral where

  postulate R : Set
  infixr 5 _+_
  infixr 6 _·_
  postulate _+_ : R → R → R
  postulate _·_ : R → R → R
  postulate integral : (R → R) → (R → R)

  syntax integral (λ x → f) = ∫ f d x

  demo = ∫ x · x + x d x
```

Coq:

```
Axiom R : Set.
Axiom plus : R -> R -> R.
Axiom times : R -> R -> R.
Axiom integral : (R -> R) -> (R -> R).
Infix "+" := (plus).
Infix "·" := (times) (at level 60).
Close Scope nat.

Notation "'∫' f '' x " := (integral (fun (x : R) => f)) (at level 20, f at next level).

Definition demo := ∫ x · x + x  x.
```

The interesting question is whether we can somehow simulate the traditional use of variables in integration. If we think of functions as expressions then $x$ appearing in $\int x^2 d x$ is a *symbol*, not a (free or bound) variable. Under this view the integral does not operate on functions but on expressions, or elements of a freely generated algebra, where the symbols are the generators. When the expressions are quotiented by equations (of a ring, a [differential algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra), or some such) we actually get some very nice algebra out if it.

Anyhow, I show below how one might begin to formalize this. The mathematician in the street will be bothered by the `$` in front of a symbol more than they will care about the formal difference between a free variable and a symbol. We could get rid of the `$` signs with sufficient syntax magic (but probably not in Agda).

```
{- A short demonstration of how one might begin to formalize symbolic
   integration. Do not expect miracles in 90 lines of Agda code. Some design
   decisions taken below are probably wrong, especially with regards to
   notation. -}

open import Relation.Nullary
open import Relation.Binary.Definitions
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

module integral where

  -- Let us imagine we have real numbers, and that ¹/₂ is a real
  postulate R : Set
  postulate ¹/₂ : R

  module Integration (Var : Set) (_≡?_ : DecidableEquality Var) where

    infixl 5 _+_
    infixl 6 _·_
    infix 20 $_
    infix 3 ∫_d_

    -- The algebra of symbolic expressions that we may integrate
    data Expr : Set where
      $_ : Var → Expr -- a symbolic variable is written as $ x
      const : R → Expr
      -_  : Expr → Expr
      _+_ : Expr → Expr → Expr
      _·_ : Expr → Expr → Expr
      sin : Expr → Expr
      cos : Expr → Expr
      ∫_d_ : Expr → Var → Expr -- an integral without closed form

    -- the function which computes integrals
    -- (no time to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm)

    ∫__ : Expr → Var → Expr

    ∫ ($ y)  x with x ≡? y
...                  | yes _ =  const ¹/₂ · $ x · $ x
...                  | no _  =  $ y · $ x

    ∫ (const a)  x = const a · $ x

    ∫ (- e)  x = - ∫ e  x

    ∫ (e₁ + e₂)  x = ∫ e₁  x + ∫ e₂  x

    ∫ (e₁ · e₂)  x = e₁ · ∫ e₂  x + e₂ · ∫ e₁  x

    ∫ (sin ($ y))  x with x ≡? y
...                      | yes _ = - cos ($ x)
    ...                      | no _ = sin ($ y) · $ x
    ∫ (sin e)  x =  ∫ (sin e) d x

    ∫ (cos ($ y))  x with x ≡? y
...                      | yes _ = sin ($ x)
    ...                      | no _ = cos ($ y) · $ x
    ∫ (cos e)  x =  ∫ (cos e) d x

    ∫ (∫ e d y)  x = ∫ (∫ e d y) d x

    {- Note the difference between:
       * an uncomputed integral ∫ f d x
       * the integral computing function ∫ f  x -}

  module Demo where

    data Var : Set where
      X Y Z : Var

    _≡?_ : DecidableEquality Var
    X ≡? X = yes refl
    X ≡? Y = no (λ ())
    X ≡? Z = no (λ ())
    Y ≡? X = no (λ ())
    Y ≡? Y = yes refl
    Y ≡? Z = no (λ ())
    Z ≡? X = no (λ ())
    Z ≡? Y = no (λ ())
    Z ≡? Z = yes refl

    open Integration Var _≡?_

    demo1 = ∫ $ X · sin ($ X) + cos ($ X)  X
-- computes to:  $ X · (- cos ($ X)) + sin ($ X) · (const ¹/₂ · $ X · $ X) + sin ($ X)

    demo2 = ∫ $ X · $ X  X
    -- computes to: $ X · (const ¹/₂ · $ X · $ X) + $ X · (const ¹/₂ · $ X · $ X)

    demo3 = ∫ sin ($ X · $ Y)  Y
    -- computes to: ∫ sin ($ X · $ Y) d Y
```

Comment: But neither have x as a free variable in the result which is what the OP wants, right?

Comment: Mike surely knows better than to prolong the historic mishandling of variables for another century.

Comment: The final parenthetical in my question was intended to express the same feeling about the mishandling of variables.  But the question I intended to ask was, indeed, whether any proof assistant can be abused to mishandle variables -- not that I would want to do such a thing, but just as a point of curiosity.  And, perhaps, if the answer is no, an argument against prolonging such mishandling...

Comment: By the way, shouldn't the type of `integral` be `(R -> R) -> (R -> R)`?

Comment: @MikeShulman: fixed, and I also point out that it makes sense to think of integration as an operator on a freely generated algebra whose generators are the integration variables.

Comment: What's throwing off the code quoting? It's getting confused at `...` and the comments at the end.